# Wrong symbols with STIX2 and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex, stix

I have problems with typesetting math symbols using stix2 fonts. Actually, I want to have \mathbfscr letters, this is the only reason why I need stix2. Simulateously, I need Times New Roman and Arial as main and sans-serif font, respectively, in text mode.

When typesetting the approximately equal sign (\approx), a ù appears instead.

When typesetting square brackets (\left[ and \right]), in a gather environment, everything is fine. In an equation environment, i get ugly round brackets and a minus sign appears as a star.

MWE (MikTex 2.9, up to date as of 14th October 2019)

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notext,notextcomp,lcgreekalpha,not1]{stix2}
\usepackage{mathtools} % this automatically loads amsmath
\usepackage{lualatex-math} % Fixes for mathematics-related LuaLaTeX issues

\usepackage{luatextra} % this loads fontspec automatically
% Font loading & selection
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    Normal Text, Times New Roman. $Re \approx 10^8$.
    \begin{gather}
        Re \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbf{\mathscr{Re}} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbf{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbfscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbfscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \rho \left[ a^2 + b^2 \right]
    \end{gather}
    \textsf{Sans-serif text, Arial.}
\begin{equation}
    \rho \left[ \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial t} \right] = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
    Re \approx 10^8
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid `luatextra`, it add nothing really useful.

Since you're using legacy math fonts (as opposed to `unicode-math`), call `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notext,notextcomp,lcgreekalpha,not1]{stix2}
\usepackage{mathtools} % this automatically loads amsmath
\usepackage{lualatex-math} % Fixes for mathematics-related LuaLaTeX issues

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
% Font loading & selection
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    Normal Text, Times New Roman. $Re \approx 10^8$.
    \begin{gather}
        Re \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbf{\mathscr{Re}} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbf{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbfscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \mathbfscr{Re} \approx 10^8 \\
        \rho \left[ a^2 + b^2 \right]
    \end{gather}
    \textsf{Sans-serif text, Arial.}
\begin{equation}
    \rho \left[ \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial t} \right] = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
    Re \approx 10^8
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the no-math option did it!
You are talking about "legacy math fonts", what would be your non-legacy choice?

Comment: @Procyon `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}`.