# Stix2 displays wrong symbols

Tags: miktex, ubuntu, mathtools, stix

I just recently switched from Windows 7 tu Ubuntu 18.04. Bevor i was working on a TeX document which worked all fine. But after i changed the OS and set MikTeX up again the `stix2` package was causing troubles, by displaying wrong symbols.
I changed nothing on my TeX-file, just using a new OS and a new MikTeX installation.

The following code

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsbsy,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\norm} {\lVert} {\rVert}

\begin{document}
    $\norm{\cdot}$
\end{document}
```

delivers
[image]. 
Obviously it should deliver something like `|| . ||`, but instead of the `||`-symbol the `\mathscr{k}`-symbol is displayed.

I already saw the question [Wrong symbols with STIX2 and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512205/wrong-symbols-with-stix2-and-lualatex). It seems to be the same problem, but i don't use LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to load the `stix2` package after, not before, packages such as `mathtools`. I.e., instead of

```
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsbsy,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\norm} {\lVert} {\rVert}
```

give

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsbsy,amsxtra}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\norm} {\lVert} {\rVert}
\usepackage{stix2}
```

a try.

Comment: This worked for me. 
If you want to add the `bm` package as well, put it at the end, or there will be to many symbol fonts declared.

Comment: Nevertheless, i am still wondering, why it worked previously in exact that loading order. But at least i got the problem fixed and can now continue working on my old file. Thanks!

Comment: @moro11 - Glad a solution was found. About too many symbol fonts being declared: The `amsxtra` package is pretty much obsolete by now -- I wouldn't load it. For sure, replace `amsbsy` with `bm`, and do load `amssymb`, since that package loads `amsfonts` automatically -- which therefore wouldn't need to be loaded separately. And, since `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, you need not load `amsmath` separately either. You should check whether or not your document truly needs `amscd`.

Comment: @moro11 - Not having ready access to older (much older?) versions of `stix2` and `mathtools`, I'm afraid I'm not in a position to provide a meaningful discussion of why some package loading ordering which "worked" at some time in the past no longer "works".

Answer (score 6):

Some of the font packages you loaded overwrote definitions from `stix2` in an incompatible way.  You almost certainly don’t want to load both `amsfonts`, `amsbsy` or `amsxtra` if you are also loading `stix2`. If you want more legacy 8-bit math fonts, you might look at `mathalpha`, `isomath` and `bm`.

You could also switch to `unicode-math` for a single, standard encoding.  This avoids the problem of 8-bit fonts putting symbols in different unused slots of math alphabets like bold, italic or calligraphic, which legacy LaTeX forced font packages to do.

Comment: Just removing the packages `amsfonts`, `amsbsy` and `amsxtra` doesn't help. I didn't tryed the tip with `unicode-math` since it seems to be a bigger change and requires the cange to LuaLaTeX... as my document is already pritty big i try to avoid major changes which could cause other problems.

Comment: @moro11 Mico’s correct about the order you have to load them in.